# PThreads Error: argument of type "void *(*)()" is incompatible

Tags: pthreads

I'm not too sure how to debug this, I am completely new to threads and am following a tutorial which worked 100%, but not for me:

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* sample() {
    printf("Thread sample. \n");
}

int main(void) {
    // Thread Creation
    pthread_t tid; // Creation of thread pointer.
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &sample, NULL); // Creation of thread.

    // Waiting for threads to be completed:
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the error: argument of type "void *(*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *(*)(void *).

All I am doing is following exactly the tutorial from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVyeJQuSFEU

Except I did not open the file and delete those things on line 317 (since it wasn't there). But VS recognizes the pthread library now.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get the error: argument of type "void ()()" is incompatible with parameter of type "void ()(void *).

The error is telling you *exactly* the problem: you defined your `void* sample()` function to take no arguments, but you should define it the way `pthread_create` expects: `void* sample(void *ptr) {...}`.

If you don't need the input `ptr` parameter, you can simply not use it.

P.S. There is an additional bug in your `sample()` function: it *promised* to return `void*`, but *doesn't*. To fix this, add `return NULL;`.

P.P.S. The tutorial may be correct in the way it adds `pthread.h` etc to Visual Studio, but is *wrong* in its use of `pthread_create()`. You'll be better off finding something more authoritative.

Comment: Thank you very much man, you were exactly right. I wish I could find someone more informative but it's hard out there in the CS world since nearly all videos are low quality and filled with difficult accents. Even the recommended Youtube channel CodeVault's video was like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9s_d28yJq0

But thank's so much for fixing it. My debugging skills aren't that great. Maybe I need a refresher on pointer. Not enough points to upvote, but I can mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @Ken I am sure there are good non-video POSIX threads introductions you can read, but if videos are your thing, this one looks reasonable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynCc-v0K-do